# Crontab log directory?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

Raspian Lite on Raspberry Pi 3:
I'm trying to output a crontab log with the following command:

```
* * * * * /home/pi/bin/pingTest.sh >> /home/pi/bin/pingLog/$( date +%Y )/$( date +%b )/l$( date +%d_%b ).log 2>&1
```

but in `/home/pi/bin/pingLog/2019/Oct/` no `l12_Oct.log` file is generated. (Directory folders are automatically generated separately).

However if I try to manually run the command into console it works and the log file is correctly generated, so my guess is that crontab doesn't like my directory(?)

How to fix this problem? PLz help ;(

crontab command:

```
* * * * * /home/pi/bin/pingTest.sh >> /home/pi/bin/pingLog/$( date +%Y )/$( date +%b )/l$( date +%d_%b ).log 2>&1
```

console command:

```
home/pi/bin/pingTest.sh >> /home/pi/bin/pingLog/$( date +%Y )/$( date +%b )/l$( date +%d_%b ).log 2>&1
```

I expect an automatically generated log file into `/home/pi/bin/pingLog/2019/Oct/` called `l12_Oct.log`

Comment: What does `ls -la home/pi/bin/pingTest.sh` say? Who owns your crontab? Who runs your crontab?

Answer (score -1):

Problem fixed, it was a directory problem:

`*/20 * * * * /home/pi/bin/pingTest.sh >> /home/pi/bin/pingLog/$( date +"\%Y" )/$( date +"\%b" )/$( date +"\%d" )/$( date +"\%d_\%b" ).txt 2>&1`

Thanks for your time :)